# Worksheet_change for multiple specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I will preface that I spent a lot of time searching and testing, but nothing ever quite worked as expected.

I am essentially creating a task list that will export to CSV in order to import. The tricky part is that the task list is determined by two user-selected variables.

The first ("C2") determines if the import is to include the "Beta tasks". This is a simple yes/no and populates the "Include" column using a simple formula.

The second ("D2") determines what Tasks are included based on the list size.

This currently works fine. Here is where I am having trouble. First is that the wokbook_change is watching for all changes on the sheet, so there is no way for me to manually choose to include/exclude tasks. How can I get the sheet to watch only for that cell to change?

Also, ideally, I would like fo the beta release to follow to primary task if I manually change to exclude. For example, set "C2" to Yes and "D2" to Medium. If I choose to manually exclude "Task 4" the corresponding Beta should also be excluded. I have this code in the workbook as a simple If statement, but could not get it to work with workbook_change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Static IsActive As Boolean
If IsActive Then Exit Sub
IsActive = True

If Range("D2").Value = "Small" Then
    Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A8").Value = "No"
    Range("A9").Value = "No"
    Range("A10").Value = ""
    Range("A11").Value = ""
    Range("A12").Value = ""
    Range("A15").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A17").Value = "No"
    Range("A19").Value = "No"
    Range("A21").Value = "No"

ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "Medium" Then
    Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A8").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A9").Value = "No"
    Range("A15").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A19").Value = "No"
    Range("A21").Value = "No"

ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "Large" Then
    Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A8").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A9").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A15").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A19").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A21").Value = "No"


ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "X-Large" Then
    Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A8").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A9").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A15").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A19").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A21").Value = "Yes"

ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "<Select>" Then
    Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A8").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A9").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A15").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A19").Value = "Yes"
    Range("A21").Value = "Yes"

End If

If Range("A15").Value = "No" Then
    Range("A16").Value = "No"
End If

If Range("A17").Value = "No" Then
    Range("A18").Value = "No"
End If

If Range("A19").Value = "No" Then
    Range("A20").Value = "No"
End If

If Range("A21").Value = "No" Then
    Range("A22").Value = "No"
End If

IsActive = False

End Sub
```

Appreciate in advance for any help. Also, I have no doubts that I am not going about this in the most efficient manner, so any suggestions on that front would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this stuff

```
Static IsActive As Boolean
If IsActive Then Exit Sub
IsActive = True
```

you can just use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent this event re-triggering itself.

You can use the [Application.Intersect Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) to test if the cell that was changed is in a specific range.

Also I suggest to use `Select Case` instead of the multiple `ElseIf` and finally you can shorten your ranges like I shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2,D5")) Is Nothing Then
        'this will only run if cells D2 or D5 was changed

        Select Case Range("D2").Value
            Case "Small":
                Range("A7,A15").Value = "Yes"
                Range("A8,A9,A17,A19,A21").Value = "No"
                Range("A10,A11,A12").Value = ""

            Case "Medium":
                'todo 
            Case "Large":
                'todo
            Case "X-Large":
                'todo
            Case "<Select>":
                'todo
            Case Else:
                'what happens if no case it true
        End Select

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```